When does the AM-GM inequality determine the infimum of a set?
Consider the set $S=\{x+x^{-1}:x\in\mathbb{Q},x>0\}$. Using the AM-GM inequality, we may obtain $$x+x^{-1}\geq 2\sqrt{x(x^{-1})}=2.$$ We may also show that $1+(1)^{-1}=2,$ but can we conclude, using this information, that $\inf S = \min S = 2$? Under what conditions does the AM-GM inequality allow us to determine the infimum, and not just a lower bound, of a set?

Do you know the definition of infimum and minimum of  a set of real numbers? By the inequality and definition the minimum of $S$ is attained when $x=1$.

@geetha290krm I believe I do. My confusion lies in whether (or under which conditions) the AM-GM inequality can determine an infimum of a set. For example, in this answer (different set), the poster claims the AM-GM is insufficient to determine the infimum, only a lower bound.
